# Prevent other software from opening my files?

Tags: windows

How can I lock a file in Windows and only give permission to a certain piece of software to open it?

I have developed some scripts for special hardware. Another piece of software (written by a big company) reads my scripts and executes them on the device. I'm going to distribute the scripts, and the customers shouldn't see the contents of the scripts, or be able to copy them. I can't encrypt the scripts -  if I encrypt them, the software can't read them (it doesn't have the option of reading an encrypted file).

Comment: Actually the best thing is to forget about it. There's no way you can do it if the software of "big company" doesn't assist you.

Comment: Depending on what the scripts are written in, obfuscation is probably the best you can do. (You could use scripts as stubs to binary code in a library but why bother?)

Comment: You have a paradox here. You wish the file to be only readable by this third party, but the third party expects normal (typically readable) files from the disk.  Unless the third-party vendor has specific support for such a function, how do you expect the operating system to make the distinction for you?

Comment: Ecryption does not prevent copying. You just get two encrypted copies.

Comment: Big Company will be Big Displeased if they find out your messing about with their software and what right do you have to do so at 3rd party sites?  You still have not specified what the "scripts" are.

Comment: I have heard that I can change the behavior of a program by hooking. Do you think that it's possible to hook the software of "big company" and make it to read the encrypted files instead of text-based files (and is it legal?) I should mention that I don't know anything about hooking, but if it is a solution, I'll learn it. What about creating virtual files? is it possible in windows to create a virtual file in the memory somehow (a file which has a path address, but it's content is in the memory), then windows thinks that this is a real file and read from it?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you would do this using kernel hooks/apis (iNotify) to decrypt the scripts before access, and encrypt them again afterwards. The difficult part is to figure out the calling program, because you may only decrypt if the calling program is the one you want the file to read, and not a text-editor for example. Probably the same is possible on Windows.